# How do you start new row on left with dynamic content in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I am working on a personal portfolio page using ReactJS. I am currently trying to create a project page that has rows of flipping cards, however, whenever the cards reach their max-width and move to the next line the card always starts in the center of the page when it needs to start on left. I have tried creating a row wrapper to float: left which breaks the application and a multitude of other ways but I would like to see the best way to create dynamic rows and columns from a mapped array and start new rows from the left. *added an image to highlight the issue*

Projects.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import Card from '../common/Card/Card';
import { PROJECTS } from "../../shared/constants/projects";
import "./projects.scss";

const Projects = () => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="grid">
                {
                    PROJECTS.map((project, i) => {
                        return (
                            <Card animatedCard={true} project={project} key={i} />
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Projects;
```

projects.scss

```
.grid {
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 20% 0 20%;
}
```

Card.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import CardFront from './CardFront';
import "./card.scss";
import CardBack from './CardBack';

const Card = props => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {props.animatedCard ?
                <div className="card-container">
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <CardBack project={props.project}/>
                        <CardFront project={props.project} />
                    </div>
                </div> : null
            }
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

card.scss

```
.button-wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 50px 25px 0px 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card-body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.card-container:hover .card-body {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-container:hover > .card-body > .side-front {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in, visibility 0.75s linear;
}

.card-side {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #8e8d8a;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 35px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1), 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.card-header-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 123px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.card-technologies {
  list-style: none;
  width: 70%;
}

.card-technologies-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}

.description {
  margin: 30px 20px 20px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 240px;
}

.side-front [class^="col-xs"]:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.side-back {
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening since you are using `text-align: center;` in your `.grid` css.
If you remove it all the cards in the row should start at the left end of the row:

```css
.grid {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 20% 0 20%;
}
```

Another alternative would be making your `.grid` a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox):

```css
.grid {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 20% 0 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;

}
```